# How to replace <switch> and <foreignObject> in an SVG file?

Tags: android, android-studio, svg, vector-graphics

I am developing an Android app and want to implement vector drawable. While using Android Vector Asset Studio in Android Studio when I imported my **.svg** file it is showing me the following error:

[image]

I visited the official [site](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html#svg) they say that such tags are not yet supported as the asset studio just can handle very simple images. I was thinking if there is any way that we could replace these tags to equivalent tags that are [supported](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html#apilevel). I don't know how to do it. Please help, thanks in advance! :)

Comment: The aren't really any equivalent tags, if there were there would be no need for the duplicates to exist would there?

Comment: Is there any way through Illustrator that I could mend the image such that .svg file has no above-mentioned tags but still has the same effect?

Comment: Open the SVG file in a text editor and remove the unsupported tags.

Comment: I already tried but the .svg failed to render.@Rotwang

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a vector image you can simply convert your SVG image to vector image from [here](http://a-student.github.io/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter.Web/) 
and then simply you can use this vector as a drawable image.

Comment: "Warning(s)! currentLocAI.svg: Met unsupported element(s): switch, i:pgf." not helpful:(

Comment: Before using Vector Asset Studio, you must add a statement to your build.gradle file i.e:  

android {
  defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
}


If you still face any difficulty, do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was able to get the vector Asset Studio to successfully import my SVG image by removing the `<foreignObject>` tags and replacing the `<switch>` tags with `<g>` tags.